# ReactMarkdown renderers not supported now

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using markdown file for loading data the initially .
If I come across an image the I want to render it in a div tag
else go with the default behaviour of paragraph

```
 const customRenderers = {

        paragraph(paragraph) {
            const {node} = paragraph
            if (node.children[0].type === 'image') {
                const image = node.children[0];
                return (
                    <div className={classes.image}>
                        <Image
                            src={`/images/posts/${posts.slug}/${image.url}`}
                            alt={image.alt}
                            width={649}
                            height={249}/>
                    </div>
                )
            }

            return <p>{paragraph.children}</p>
        }
    }
```

Can someone  help me  in removing  this warning

```
 <ReactMarkdown renderers ={customRenderers}>{posts.content}</ReactMarkdown>
```

```
 Warning: please use `components` instead of `renderers`
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [here](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown#appendix-b-components) in the official react-markdown documentation in Github, you should use the components prop rather than renderers. Ultimately, exactly what the warning tells you.

Please note the [minimum effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/8003058) required for a question, a simple google search would've sufficed to find the answer, in your case.

Comment: Type {paragraph(any): any} is not assignable to type Components 
 Inspection info: Reports incorrect type of:
a parameter in a function call
a return value
an assigned expression